# How to set dynamic connection manager using SQL Server authentication which use password at run time from a table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I want to connect to SQL Server using SQL Server authentication in connection manager in SSIS. I want that every time when the package runs and connects to server it should use user id and password from the table created in SQL Server at run time.

The reason to get password from table is that every 6 months I need to change the password as per the policy so I don't want to login to each and every SSIS package and change the password there. I want to change the password in table and redirect that password through variable/expression to the connection manager password window.

Comment: So you need second database to hold passwords? In my opinion you should simply configure AD authentication.

Comment: Use a Service account for it with no Password expiry.

Comment: Why can't you do this?   What step are you stuck on?   Surely you know how to query a table.

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore the idea that saving passwords in plain text makes changing them every six months a futile effort.  It is a far greater security risk to have them stored in plain text ANYWHERE.

The solution is to NOT use an SQL Login.  Have these services run under a specific Windows User and grant that User the necessary access.

An alternative is to explain the problem to the Security admin and get an account setup that does not expire but that can only login locally as a service. Don't use that account for anything else.

HTH,
Sean

Comment: Wouldn't the account already assigned to Agent (or whatever proxy is chosen) be a service account? And that account should be granted access to what is needed.

Comment: Oh, I saw service and thought Windows Service, not SSIS.  The solution is still a dedicated Windows Authentication that does not expire.